# Binding Dictionary<String, Int32> by keys to ListBox and selected item values to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Dictionary<String, Int32[]>` which is named `someDict`. Keys are binding to `ListBox.ItemsSource`. Values of `ListBox.SelectedItem` must to be binding to `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. How to do it?

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=someDict.Keys}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make some changes to your `XAML`.

1. `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` should be the whole `Dictionary`. To diplay `Key` values use an `ItemTemplate`
2. Modify the `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox`

   ```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=someDict}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Value}"/>
   ```